# Correct Sander Markings on Wood after Stain has properly dried

Tags: wood, woodworking, staining, sanding, sander

[image]I re-processed my doors, and got to the third layer of stain. Unbeknownst to me,I had terrible sanding marks in my doors which I can see clearly through the third. Is there anyway to fix this without having to completely take off the stains i.e start all over again??

Comment: @HerrBag, can you please give me some advice on how to save this project?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you neither sanded with the grain or used a fine enough sandpaper in order to prepare for staining.  I think you have to go sand it down and start over.  Those likely would have been visible before staining.

Comment: I agree, sand it down, then go over it with 220 grit (my typical choice) sand paper, by hand, to smooth it out. Also be careful with how you remove sanding dust, a horse hair brush is good for removing dust without scratching the wood.

Comment: I did sand with the grain except at the edge where I used a detail sander to go sideways, and I used a fine sanding block to sand before staining. What is the advantage of sanding this again by hand?

Comment: If you sand again, the way to do better is to sand with the grain. You'll need to remove enough material to get rid of the sideways scratches. This might require a different tool or technique, so it is worth experimenting. Unfortunately, many finishes (including stains) make scratches more visible. You can check for scratches before re-applying finish by setting the surface horizontal, putting a light low over the far end, and putting your eyes low over the near end. The reflected glare of the light tends to make blemishes more obvious.